# Increment a column value based on uniqueness of other column values

Tags: mysql, sql, database, auto-increment

I have a table, to which I need to add an increment column, however the increment should happen based on the existing values in the other columns.

```
select * from mytable;

first_col    second_col
   A             B
   A             C
   A             D
   A             E
   A             B
   A             D
```

Now, I want to add another column, say new_column whose value increments uniquely on the basis of the first_col and second_col.

The column should be populated like these :

```
first_col    second_col    new_col
   A             B            1
   A             C            1
   A             D            1
   A             E            1
   A             B            2
   A             D            2
   A             B            3
```

Is it possible to do this using some sort of an MySQL in built auto increment strategy.

Answer (score 1):

Using a temporary table with an auto_incremented id column you could do

```
create temporary table tt (
  id int auto_increment primary key,
  col1 varchar(32),col2 varchar(32));

insert into tt
select col1, col2 from origtable;

select col1, col2, 
  (select count(*)+1 from tt s
    where s.col1=m.col1 and s.col2=m.col2
    and s.id<m.id) n
frm tt m
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be a more standard approach. Only that, I will not make the sequence generator table not temporary.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in increment method in MySQL, but you can do this with either correlated subqueries or variables:

```
select t.*,
       (@rn := if(@c = concat(first_col, ':', second_col), @rn + 1,
                  @c := concat(first_col, ':', second_col), 1, 1
                 )
       ) as new_col
from mytable t cross join
     (select @rn := 0, @c := '') params
order by first_col, second_col;
```

Note:  this re-orders the results.  If you want the results in the original order, then you need a column that specifies that ordering.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do it, replace `col1val` and `col2val` with the values to be inserted.

```
INSERT INTO mytable (first_col, second_col, new_col)
VALUES (SELECT col1val, col2val SUM(COUNT(*), 1)
        FROM mytable
        GROUP BY first_col, second_col
        HAVING first_col = col1val AND second_col = col2val)
```

Note that this is an insert query, and will affect only newly inserted values.

Comment: This will update the values of the new column only one time.I want that  I may keep persisting new rows, and the new column to pick up the value automatically.